# New rails installation with error when entering url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, url

**SOLVED** In the /etc/apache2/vhosts.d/default.conf we inserted the following

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule "^/?$" "http://ourpage.com/projects"
```

**--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

We installed rails on a new server. When we try access the `url` we get redirected to `ourstuff/public` which is not desired. In `ourstuff` there is `app, config, public` etc.

EDIT: 
Could it be that the mod passenger does not work properly?
The following from `public` is displayed in the browser (see scrshot). My collegaue said its from the the documentary root from the apache config file.

[public](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQUCF.jpg)

When we try the usual url `xyz.com/ourstuff` like from our other systems we get this error

**Routing Error**

```
No route matches [GET] "/ourstuff"

Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
```

Does anyone have an idea why this is?

Thank you in adcvance.

Comment: You need to provide the relevant details about the server and configuration and how you actually want to mount the rails application. It seems like you have mounted rails on the root of the domain so that calling `/ourstuff` will actually look for that route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you set up your routes?

In your config/routes.rb file add:

```
get '/ourstuff', to: 'controller#action', as: 'ourstuff'
```

This means when your server receives a get request to yourapp.com/ourstuff, it will send the request to the controller and action you specify.

It's then up to you to put in the required logic in that action, and present the relevant template. See:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

EDIT: You need to add this line inbetween:

```
myqpp::Application.routes.draw do
```

and the final

```
end
```

on its own line. i.e.

```
myqpp::Application.routes.draw do
  root :to => 'projects#index' 
  get '/ourstuff', to: 'controller#action', as: 'ourstuff'
end
```

Once more, you will need to set up a controller, an action for that controller with the necessary logic, and a template to render at the end.

Comment: thank you for your help. in my config file I have the following so far `myqpp::Application.routes.draw do
      resources :...
      resources :...
      resources :...
      root :to => 'projects#index'
    end`

Comment: Edited answer to include where to put the line

Comment: Thanks! It works. But the very strange thing here is that on the other systems your offered line is not in the script. And the other systems work. How can that be? Well with your line everything seems to work. The dababases' data ist displayed. I just don't want any trouble later.

Comment: Now, when I log in it suddenly redirects me to the upper screenshot page which is weired. When I type the /myapp in the browser the login was successful. What is going on here?

Comment: Is the other app a rails application? When you enter a URL the first thing rails does is look in the routes.rb file, and if it doesn't throw an error then it means the route was in there somewhere. You can pull in routes from other files so if other files are being required the route may be defined there

Comment: And can you post the output from your terminal when you get redirected please?

Comment: The two routes.rb files are identical. I have never needed the output from my terminal. How do I get this?